# Upload to Google Drive through browser

Tags: javascript, php, file-upload, google-drive-api

I am having this issue with uploading files to a google drive using a service/test user, but the thing is that i want to skip the oauth entirely. I wanna have an upload form ready for users (teachers for example) to upload their files to drive without the need of signing in/logging in/verifying identity/etc...
I need to do this with javascript only.

I tried using .json which worked. but i dont think i can have it run on the browser because i am using app.listen() with a port given, and it runs on cmd using the "node index.js(for example)" command. So i need a java script or a php substitute/snippet.

Comment: Hi Ameen, welcome to SO! Make sure to add some concrete code example that we can work with to provide you an answer. This form is not meant for software suggestions or to have other people write software solutions for you. An existing problem must be at hand and then we are more than happy to help you :)

Answer (score 0):

To write to a google drive account you need permission of the owner of that account, because it contains private user data.

In the case of client side JavaScript, your only option is Implicit flow, which requires that the user authorize the request every time they login to the application.

## server sided alternatives to consider.

If you would like to consider a server sided option. I have an couple of alternatives for you.

First if you are uploading to a folder on google drive that you the developer control.   Then you could use a service account. This service account is like a dummy user you could share the folder with the service account, which will grant it access to the folder. Then within your server sided code the service account can access it when ever it needs without requesting authorization of the user.

Second if you are uploading to your users drive accounts.  You can use Oauth2 and request authorization of the user once.  At that time  you store the refresh token returned to you, then when the user comes back again you can just use the refresh token to request a new access token and upload to their google drive account.  This solution will only require that the user authorize your application once.

both of the above solutions will work with, node.js or php, it just has to be server sided.

## drive service account php

Here is a basic service account authorization example.  Remember once you create the service account, to share the service account email address with a folder on your google drive account that you want to upload to.

[How to create Google Oauth2 Service account credentials.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=asrCdWFrF0A)

```
<?php
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

if (php_sapi_name() != 'cli') {
    throw new Exception('This application must be run on the command line.\n');
}

use Google\Service\Drive;

const CREDENTIALS = 'C:\Development\FreeLance\GoogleSamples\Credentials\ServiceAccountCred.json';
const SCOPES = [Google_Service_Drive::DRIVE_METADATA_READONLY];

printf("Service Account Access to google drive api.\n");

// Create service account client, with drive scopes.
$client = new Google\Client();
$client->setAuthConfig(CREDENTIALS);
$client->setScopes(SCOPES);

// Create Google Drive service
$service = new Drive($client);

// Print files that the service account has access to.
try {

    $optParams = array(
        'pageSize' => 10,
        'fields' => 'files(id,name,mimeType)',
        'q' => 'mimeType = "application/vnd.google-apps.folder" and "root" in parents',
        'orderBy' => 'name'
    );
    $results = $service->files->listFiles($optParams);
    $files = $results->getFiles();

    if (empty($files)) {

        $data = json_decode(file_get_contents(CREDENTIALS), true);

        print "No files found.\n";
        printf("Please upload a file or share a file with the service account at (%s) ", $data["client_email"]);
    } else {
        print "Files:\n";
        foreach ($files as $file) {
            $id = $file->id;

            printf("%s - (%s) - (%s)\n", $file->getId(), $file->getName(), $file->getMimeType());
        }
    }
} catch (Exception $e) {
    // TODO(developer) - handle error appropriately
    echo 'Message: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: is it possible for you to supply me with a php snippet? Id be thankful. Right now i am looking into this: https://ben.akrin.com/google-drive-api-file-upload-script/

Comment: for what service account?

Comment: to be honest anything that can auto authorise or skip it. php would be good